# What is the use of Access-Control-Allow-Headers for unauthenticated endpoints?

Tags: cors

I understand that servers might want to prevent bad origins somehow stealing certain data and crafting a request to request some authorized data from a different domain. Such as using "Authorization" header etc., what is the use of Access-Control-Allow-Headers for unauthenticated endpoints? In such cases, shouldn't servers just accept all headers?

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the broader [CORS system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to restrict JavaScript calls for a page running on one domain (origin) from accessing resources on another domain.

Web browsers block all cross origin requests by default (see [same-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)).

The browser enforces the control but needs to ask the server what the policy is. If the frontend code makes a call to a different origin the browser requests the resource headers. If those headers allow cross origin requests then the browser makes the request.

One of the optional CORS policy items is the one you ask about ([Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)). By default a [handful of headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header) are always sent. If you want to allow sending additional headers then you have to specify them.

Comment: *Web browsers block all cross origin requests by default*. No: try opening your browser's Console tab on this page and running `fetch('https://example.com')`.

Answer (score 1):

Specific example: think about the login endpoint (`/auth/login` or whatever). That's an unauthenticated endpoint (because the user is not logged in at the time they call it), but you probably want all the CORS protections on it so that your login endpoint can only be called by your javascript and not another tab.

Why? Because otherwise you can get "[login CSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#login-csrf)" where the user thinks they're logged into a site on their account, but in the background a different tab silently logged them into the attackers account, and now the user may upload sensitive files or whatever to the attacker's account.

Comment: _all the CORS protections_ [...] What are those "CORS protections" you're referring to? How is activating CORS on that endpoint supposed to protect from login CSRF, exactly?